# How to include a field from the joining table in the queryset?

Tags: django, orm, django-rest-framework

We have Django Rest Framework at work, however I'm a front-end developer who's decided to do a little bit of DRF for his next open-source project.

I don't wish to copy-paste a lot of code, as you can see all of my serializers, models, etc... [on GitHub](https://github.com/Wildhoney/TravelMap/tree/master/backend/api).

I've asked the developers at work. One said I should override `to_representation` which doesn't seem right, as we're building the serialized model from scratch. Whereas the other Django developer at work suggested I look into [custom relation fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields).

Essentially given the following serializer, how would I include the "type" (badly named) column from my joining table in my queryset:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'countries')
```

In pseudo-code I'm looking for something like the following, so when you get a user, you also get associated `countries`, which is working just fine via the many-to-many relationship, as well as the "type" from the joining table:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'countries', 'pinned.type')
```

I'd expect a JSON response of something like the following:

```
{
    "username": "wildhoney",
    "countries": [
        { "country_id": 4, "type": 1 },
        { "country_id": 5, "type": 2 },
        { "country_id": 6, "type": 3 }
    ]
}
```

At the moment I only receive a list of `country_id`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to want to use a nested relation like this:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('order', 'title', 'duration')

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

Source: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

So for your situation it would be:

```
class PinnedSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pinned
        fields = ('type', 'country_id')

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    pins = PinnedSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'countries', 'pins')
```

Newest version tested with actual project:

```
class PinnedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='country.id')
    class Meta:
        model = Pinned
        fields = ('type', 'country_id')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pinned_set = PinnedSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'pinned_set')
```

Output:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "username": "bobdole",
    "pinned_set": [
        {
            "type": 1,
            "country_id": 250
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I do that and get: Field name `type` is not valid for model `Country`. Is it because `type` is on the `PinnedSerializer`, not the `CountrySerializer`?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misunderstood. I thought `type` was a field on `Country`. It looks like you might be doing it a little backwards and you'd want a `pins` list instead of `countries` in your response.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not sure how to achieve that. [Source code is on Github](https://github.com/Wildhoney/TravelMap/tree/master/backend/api). For `/user/wildhoney` [I receive this](https://pastebin.com/HfAEXvtj), and [I ideally want this](https://pastebin.com/zAQKh09G).

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of how I would approach it. I guess you could name the field `countries` still, but I named it `pins`. This makes a lot more sense, because `Pinned` is related to `User`, but `Country` is not.

Comment: Strangely with your answer I get exactly the same: `"countries": [4]`.

Comment: Does it look exactly the same as mine?

Comment: I think so, unless I'm missing something: https://github.com/Wildhoney/TravelMap/blob/master/backend/api/serializers.py

Comment: Yea, it does look like I would expect. Are you not getting any results under the `pins` key?

Comment: Absolutely nothing from `pins`. Although I don't receive any errors, either.

Comment: I can seem to access the `type` by using the `pinned_set` that's apparently automatically created in a `ManyToMany` relationship, as seen with my [`PinnedSerializer`](https://pastebin.com/YWsKDsnc). However I'm not sure how to specify that with the `fields` property. I tried something like `fields = ('id', 'pinned_set__type')` but I can't quite figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, what if you use a `pinned_set = PinnedSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)` and use `pinned_set` in the `UserSerializer` fields. And `PinnedSerializer` will stay the same.

Comment: [All in the `UserSerializer`](https://pastebin.com/xzge5eYh)? That just gives me the `id` again. [I *solved* it](https://pastebin.com/2um5K4Ck) using `to_representation` but that seems overkill. Surely there must be a more automated way?

Comment: Yea, I was avoiding suggesting that method, since I didn't think that's what you wanted to do(as you mentioned it in the original post). Theoretically, just using the Serializer as I've written it should work. I tried testing with your project, but it was missing some information from your settings.py or something

Comment: Sorry. It's because I'm relying on env vars to prevent committing the DB credentials to the repository. However it's only a throwaway DB on a Heroku instance, so it doesn't really matter. I've [committed the DB credentials](https://github.com/Wildhoney/TravelMap/commit/2d1d5fb02461584236b6cf186113f40aca1407d8) for the moment, so the project should work just as I see it. Hopefully this helps you. Thanks for the help up-to-now!

Comment: You're right though. I absolutely don't want to use `to_representation`.

Comment: I noticed my `to_representation` was returning a list of a list. [I've changed it to use `value.pinned_set.first()`](https://pastebin.com/4MAiFc9D) for it to output correctly. However, because I'm using `first` it seems as though my relationship is somehow wrong?

Comment: @Wildhoney I realize it's not optimal, but if you're willing to accept the data under `pinned_set` key, you can use the code in my updated answer. I've tested it in your code and it worked as desired(I believe).

Comment: Ah perfect! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. It was a learning experience for me, too :)

Comment: btw, I created a user or two and a Country in your database. Country ID 250